# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) - what's wrong?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

(Sorry for my English)

This is a log of my console:

```
anton@anton-X451CA:~$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
anton@anton-X451CA:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

What should I do? I understand that it appears when I try entering without a password, but I am dont confirmed password, and 'root'/empty string doesn't help.

Comment: You should specify the correct password :p Is this a fresh installation?

Comment: try the password as **root**

Comment: @ArunVitto Already tried:

anton@anton-X451CA:~$ mysql -h localhost -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: @fancyPants Yes, i am reinstalled client and server with that commands:

sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you installed this fresh, you usually execute

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

afterwards. There you also set the initial password for your root account (note, that this is not the root account you have in Linux).

When you installed version 5.7. or higher the initial password is not blank anymore. You can find it in the error log. Find this log by looking in your my.cnf file. Default directory is `/var/log/mysql`, I think.

Comment: Ok, i am entered mysql_secure_installation and there is result:

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I tried 'root' and empty string in field for password - the result is same.

Comment: Have you read the rest of my answer? The password can be found in the error log.

Comment: i found my.cnf file in /etc/mysql/my.cnf, there is file's content:
https://pastebin.com/CieqCgDW

I dont see anything what can give me a hint.

Comment: About error log (/var/log/mysql/error.log, as your say). I saw only this notes:
https://pastebin.com/KcFbmq4V

Comment: I am fixed that thing! :)... I am add [mysqld]
skip-grant-tables in my.cnf, that's helps enter in console without password (mysql -u root). After that i change the password with command (UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('root'), plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;). That's all.

Thank you for helping. :)

Answer (score 11):

I solved the problem, when:

Change the file my.cnf (in my Ubuntu-system he is placed at /etc/mysql/my.cnf). In the end i added that code:

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
```

That's helps enter in condole as anyone user without pass. Restart the server:
sudo service mysql restart

Enter in the mysql-console:

```
mysql -u root
```

Change the password for user root:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('root'), plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

exit the console:

```
\q
```

Remove (or use commentary) for that in my.cnf (we dont need that settings now):

```
#[mysqld]
#skip-grant-tables
```

restart mysql-server:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

That's all. :)

Comment: `UPDATE` did not work but this did: `alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'PASSWORD'`